# XCode - How to change button destiny with segmented control

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm building an app right now and I have a problem with the combination of button and segmented control, if it's even possible.

Right now I have a segemented control, where you can chose between 7 different values. On the same page, I have a button leading to the next page. Now I want my button to lead to a different page, depending on the selected value in the segemented control.

My segemented control is located in my ViewController.swift and my button in Main.storyboard.

I looked in the code of it and found the destination of the first page the button has to lead to, but I can't figure out how to make it dependent on the segemented control. Simple "if" commands seems not to work in ".storyboard",

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

not sure that you can do this from just the storyboard, I would have the button reference an `IBAction` in the view controller. The action could use a switch statement (or a series of if/else statements) to call different segues based on the state of the segmented control.

Comment: Hi C1FR1, thanks for your help :)  I think with "Sege.selectedSegmentIndex===0" etc. I could check the Segmented control there, but how do I change the destiny of a button in the ViewController ? I'd only know how to do it in the storyboard

Comment: I have not really done it this way before, so the best advice I can give you is to look at this

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1